# Counting the hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchy

I have a table with a hierarchy:

```
CREATE TABLE mng 
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    manager_id INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO mng (id, name, manager_id) VALUES (1, 'Lola', NULL);
INSERT INTO mng (id, name, manager_id) VALUES (2, 'Bella', NULL);
INSERT INTO mng (id, name, manager_id) VALUES (3, 'Lo', 1);
INSERT INTO mng (id, name, manager_id) VALUES (4, 'Ann', 2);
INSERT INTO mng (id, name, manager_id) VALUES (5, 'Ki', 3);
INSERT INTO mng (id, name, manager_id) VALUES (6, 'Qo', 5);
```

I need to print all top managers (where `manager_id` is `NULL`) with their subordinates count (including all levels)

```
   id   |   cnt
--------+---------
   1    |   3
   2    |   1
```

upd
was trying something like this:

```
WITH DirectReports(ManagerID, Employee) AS   
(  
    SELECT id, 0 AS Employee  
    FROM mng 
    WHERE manager_id IS NULL  
  
    UNION ALL  
  
    SELECT e.id, Employee + 1  
    FROM mng AS e  
    INNER JOIN DirectReports AS d  
    ON e.manager_id  = d.ManagerID    
)  
SELECT ManagerID, Employee  
FROM DirectReports  
ORDER BY ManagerID;
```

got level number, but how to get count?

Comment: Iam using sqlfiddle) but lets say its MS SQL Server 2017

Comment: Your original code was not working in SQLFiddle. You create a table called Employee, but all other code then references mng. Similarly, the column name in the create table script is called manager_id, but the cte uses mng_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your original code is you lose track of the "top manager". You can, however, retain this within the CTE, and simply have it listed for every employee:

```
WITH DirectReports(id, TopMgr, ManagerID, Employee) AS   
(  
    SELECT id, id, NULL, 0 AS Employee
    FROM mng 
    WHERE manager_id  IS NULL  
  
    UNION ALL  
  
    SELECT e.id, d.TopMgr, e.manager_id, 1 AS Employee
    FROM mng AS e  
    INNER JOIN DirectReports AS d  
    ON e.manager_id  = d.id   
)  
SELECT TopMgr, SUM(Employee)
FROM DirectReports  
GROUP BY TopMgr
ORDER BY TopMgr
```

Output:

```
    TopMgr  EmployeeCount
1   3
2   1
```

Answer (score 1):

First you can get the employees under manager, top level manager. Later, you can count the employees under top level manager.

```sql
;WITH DirectReports(EmployeeId, ManagerID, TopMostManagerId) AS   
(  
    SELECT id, Null, id 
    FROM #mng 
    WHERE manager_id IS NULL  
  
    UNION ALL  
  
    SELECT e.id, e.manager_Id, d.TopMostManagerId  
    FROM #mng AS e  
    INNER JOIN DirectReports AS d  
    ON e.manager_id  = d.EmployeeId    
)  
SELECT TopMostManagerId, COUNT(EmployeeId) as CountOfEmployees
FROM DirectReports 
WHERE ManagerID is not null -- excludes toplevel manager
group by TopMostManagerId
```

| TopMostManagerId | CountOfEmployees |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |

Comment: @user2050247, if it answers your question, please click the tick mark and mark it as answer, so it is helpful for others in future